# Working with Facebook login from localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have a React/Horizon app with facebook login.
I am wondering if there is any option to work with facebook login from localhost?

Comment: I found this
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/
I manage to run https:localhost:3000 and it works with a Facebook app in Live mode

Answer (score 76):

There are some other good answers here. However I want to add information about how to create a Test app (as recommended by Facebook).

Go to the page to manage Facebook apps (you, the admin must be logged in): https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Hover over the block containing your live Facebook app and click on the three dots button that appears on the bottom right corner. Then select *Create Test App* from the menu.

[image]

> The test app will be created with a snapshot of your production app's settings. After this, you can independently edit the settings of your test app without affecting your production app.

See the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/

Regarding the rest of the setup:

- keep your app *in Development* mode
- go to *Settings -> Basic* (left hand menu) and

  - enter "localhost" for the *App Domain*
  - change your *Site URL* to the localhost version (e.g. http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook)

Here are some (Jan 2022) screenshots of my test app settings, which I just use for Facebook login.

*Settings -> Basic*
[image: Settings -> Basic screenshot]

*Settings -> Advanced*
[image: Settings -> Advanced screenshot]

*Facebook Login -> Settings*
[image]

Comment: hen entering `localhost`, I get: `App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct at least one of these domains: localhost` Facebook is an absolute pain to set up, when it took me 10 minutes for the Google login button.

Comment: @JeremyThille I see there is a separate stackoverflow for this problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505276/app-domains-must-match-the-domain-of-the-facebook-web-games-url-https-mobile ... I'm unsure how you'd get this error if you followed my instructions (creating your test app from the main app) and changing both the app domain and the site URL. Please check you have done all those

Comment: I have checked and tried all answers in the link you pointed at. Nothing works. I can save `localhost` both in App domains and website URL, but I'm still getting `The method FB.login can no longer be called from http pages` in my localhost console. There's no way to develop a Facebook login locally, I'll do it directly from the HTTPS production server (thanks Facebook)

Comment: That sounds frustrating! 

BTW, it's not "localhost" for the site URL. it should be something like http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook - I will change my answer to be more clear in that regard.

Comment: Worked like a charm! For those who have issues, make sure that you update the App ID and App Secret in your settings to match those of the test app.

Comment: After trying with loads of other solutions (change site URL, create test app, change callback URL, ...) I finally had to use ngrok to do this. So disappointed to see big tech companies treat developers as second class users.

Comment: @mahdix my experience is that integration with any of the big tech megaliths is a challenge. From outdated documentation to inexplicable processes (caused by various upgrades over time), it's generally a nightmare. I am sorry my answer didn't work for you, but I am glad you found a way in the end with ngrok.

Comment: @Vlad I would imagine the app ID and secret would only be different if you created the test app manually - not using the steps in my answer, or you manually changed them. Thanks though for commenting and letting us all know about this requirement

Comment: @Dagmar Actually I followed your steps. Then I noticed that the app ID and secret of the test app were different from those of the live app, so I used them in the test configuration of my Spring Boot app. This way, my app would connect to the test Facebook app in test mode and to the live one in production mode.

Comment: @Dagmar Does it work the same way for Instagram's basic display API on localhost? I would really appreciate your suggestion on this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984334/instagram-basic-display-api-error-invalid-scope-basic-or-invalid-redirect**

Comment: I get the error: _"URL Blocked - This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings..."_ (on the FB login page). But I can't add any URL with _localhost_ under "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" (Facebook Login > Settings) because then it says _"http://localhost redirects are automatically allowed while in development mode only and do not need to be added here."_ Apparently, that's not true, though, so it won't work for me. (Yes, I'm using a FB test app in development mode).

Comment: @bass-t I checked my app's settings (and will add some new screenshots to my answer shortly). I see there is another setting on Facebook login -> Settings called "Redirect URI Validator". Also I do have a URL for "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" -> https://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback

Comment: It seems like the method does not work anymore in 2023, and tunelling is one of the alternatives

Comment: @chygo Thanks for your comment. I just tested my dev (http localhost) environment and I can still log in via Facebook using this same setup

Comment: @Dagmar The problem now is, in the "Valid Oauth Request URIs", Facebook does not even allow setting up a localhost url (it will show an error, and "Save changes" button keeps disabled), I am not sure how you could set it up

Comment: @chygo I see - I went into my app settings and when I try save I get an error for the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" that says "http://localhost redirects are automatically allowed while in development mode only and do not need to be added here.". 

I created a new test app for my production app and even though I never entered an OAuth Redirect URIs the login worked. I think it just accepts any localhost URI when you're in "Development" mode (a toggle at the top of the dashboard)

Answer (score 28):

You need to register as facebook developer and create you app there. Once you have your web app registered you can go to your app and click on add product.

Add Facebook Login. Then enable Web OAuth Login and add your localhost in the textfield below and save, you should be able to access it. Attaching a sample screenshot of my facebook app. [image: here]

Comment: Not working for me - it's only accepting HTTPS URLs.

Comment: Then you need to activate HTTPS on your localhost. Here's one guide if you're on macOS or Linux: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian even with https on localhost, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Login with facebook for my local setup has successfully supported `https` (`https://development.local`) and it is working (via nginx). But the beta version of it that is only using `http` is not working. Still struggling how to make it work. Seems to me facebook login is not possible with http even i did not enforce https on the developer console.

Comment: For enabling https on localhost (for nginx server only), check this forked gist https://gist.github.com/josephdicdican/c4a9401b11522f07802959305583491c

Comment: on Facebook developer blog they say `You will still be able to use HTTP with “localhost” addresses, but only while your app is still in development mode.
`  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/  I guess they mean `localhost` not `localhost:3000` or any port

Answer (score 21):

*Disclaimer: This answer was written in 2019 and I have not been able to keep up with the latest changes introduced by Facebook, this is here for reference purposes.*

---

So in my case doing the following things worked for me.

1. Make sure your application is in development mode

[image: Application Mode - in development]

2. Make sure you don't have anything in Valid OAuth Redirect URIs when working from localhost

[image: Valid OAuth Redirect URIs]

3. Make sure you don't have anything in App Domains also

[image: App Domains]

4. Make sure you have entered localhost in your site url

[image: Website URL]

Comment: Done all that, still getting `The method FB.login can no longer be called from http pages.` What an absolute pain to set up :(

Comment: Your site must have SSL configured even locally

Comment: @JeremyThille Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the exact same issue that you have described.

Comment: In my case I realized that the error was related to importing an sdk with a different app-id in the cdn. I had forgotten that I was trying with CDN before importing SDK.  Removing import from cdn solved my problem

Answer (score 16):

> I would like to add an update: **July 2019**

Facebook now **allow localhost automatically in development mode** and it is blocked in production mode. All you have to do is turn on development mode in your app settings and you are good to go.

**You do not need to add `localhost` as a redirect URL anymore.**

Here you can see the error at the Redirect URLs when I'm trying to add localhost.

[image: Facebook developer page]

Comment: What page is this/where is it located?

Comment: Local host gets added with https after you click save.

Comment: Now it fails when I request the FB `access_token`, saying the domain of this URL is not in the domains of the app -- although I whitelisted `localhost` as app domain (in Settings > Basic) - January 2022.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a tunneling tool like https://ngrok.com/ which is free for at least one instance. Then you can create a test App as already suggested and use the ngrok generated urls in this test app.[image]

Comment: I can't add the ngrok domain to the app domains, I receive this message: https://ibb.co/Z8mmsnv

Answer (score 2):

After test I see that we don't need to setup anything in facebook app 
(even `Site URL` don't need to be localhost)

Just need to use `https://localhost` instead of `http://localhost`. Then login work and we able to receive response.

Note: If you see SSL warning after you enter `https://localhost` to browser. Just click on `Advance` -> `Process to ... (unsafe)`

Answer (score 2):

The method FB.login can no longer be called from http pages.localhost, I get: App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct at least one of these domains: localhost

Answer (score 2):

Using something like [local-ssl-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-ssl-proxy) is an easy way to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

So I also have problem with working with Facebook Login from localhost in React and Express and I got this info:
"The method FB.login can no longer be called from http pages". After click login button, app just crashed.
My solution to fix this mess, was delete Facebook cookie from this localhost page. After this, I still have this error about http, but I can proceed and test login options.

Other solution is working in incognito mode.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Firebase to log into Facebook and honestly, the easiest thing was to just get your localhost served over HTTPS. I used [ssl-serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-serve) for it, since I was working on a very basic ESM app with no build tools. But most build pipelines (e.g. Vue's `vue-cli`, React, etc.) have a CLI option for SSL as well.

What I used:

```
cd src && npx ssl-serve --ssl --clipless --port 5000 --silent
```

Then you just accept the self-signed cert ("Advanced" > "Continue" in Chrome/Brave) and you won't need to mess around with swapping the redirect URIs or domains under your Facebook app's config, nor the Facebook App IDs on Firebase.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook provide Test App for your current app to get access to localhost environment. Create a test app on facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-apps/

and use the API and Secret to get testing on localhost.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to share my experience for anyone who use firebase authentication combine with facebook login. Below solution work for me:

First, set your App Mode is **development** at https://developers.facebook.com.

Next, when you enable facebook login in Firebase Authentication, firebase will give you a link call **OAuth redirect URI**, you will have to add this link to the **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs** field in the setting page of your facebook app (inside tab Facebook Login). This is the most important step.

Finally, you don't need to do anything else. Good luck.

Answer (score -3):

If you're using react and your local server is on http and still getting the error run this in the terminal to start up an https localhost

**Windows:**

set HTTPS=true&&npm start

**Windows Powershel:**

($env:HTTPS = "true") -and (npm start)

**Linux and macOS (Bash):** 

HTTPS=true npm start

when it opens in the browser
click **Advanced** and **proceed**