# Login with facebook on localhost without https

Tags: javascript, facebook-login

I am trying to implement login with facebook on my website.
I configured app id and URL everything properly.
Problem is I am running on HTTP as I am on localhost.
When I try to log in it gives me this error

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

I have checked many answers on StackOverflow but seems like those are a very old answer and things have changed now.
Can anyone tell me if its possible to login without https on localhost?

Comment: I suggest following this helpful guide: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800216/working-with-facebook-login-from-localhost/39800296](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800216/working-with-facebook-login-from-localhost/39800296)

Comment: That is the answer from Sep 2016. And as I mention I think things have changed now. If you can check comment in that answer someone says it's only accepting HTTPS only.