# Instagram Basic Display API Error - Invalid scope: ['basic'] OR Invalid redirect_uri

Tags: instagram, magento2, instagram-api

**I'm using Magento 2.4.1, installed Social Login Extension and getting below error while login to Instagram, I'm using Hybrid auth libraries to login.**

> "error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid
> scope: ['basic']"}

**You can check the screenshot below,**

[image: Screenshot]

> **Instagram.php**

```
<?php
/*!
* HybridAuth
* http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net | https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth
*  (c) 2009-2012 HybridAuth authors | http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/licenses.html
*/
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Providers;

/**
* Hybrid_Providers_Instagram (By Sebastian Lasse - https://github.com/sebilasse)
*/
class Instagram extends \Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2
{
    // default permissions
    public $scope = "basic";

    /**
    * IDp wrappers initializer
    */
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        // Provider api end-points
        $this->api->api_base_url  = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/";
        $this->api->authorize_url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/";
        $this->api->token_url     = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
    }

    /**
    * load the user profile from the IDp api client
    */
    public function getUserProfile()
    {
        $data = $this->api->api("users/self/");

        if ($data->meta->code != 200) {
            throw new \Exception("User profile request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an invalid response.", 6);
        }

        $this->user->profile->identifier  = $data->data->id;
        $this->user->profile->displayName = $data->data->full_name ? $data->data->full_name : $data->data->username;
        $this->user->profile->description = $data->data->bio;
        $this->user->profile->photoURL    = $data->data->profile_picture;

        $this->user->profile->webSiteURL  = $data->data->website;
        
        $this->user->profile->username    = $data->data->username;

        return $this->user->profile;
    }
    /**
    *
    */
    public function getUserContacts()
    {
        // refresh tokens if needed
        $this->refreshToken();

        //
        $response = array();
        $contacts = array();
        $profile = ((isset($this->user->profile->identifier))?($this->user->profile):($this->getUserProfile()));
        try {
            $response = $this->api->api("users/{$this->user->profile->identifier}/follows");
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception("User contacts request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an error: $e");
        }
        //

        if (isset($response) && $response->meta->code == 200) {
            foreach ($response->data as $contact) {
                try {
                    $contactInfo = $this->api->api("users/".$contact->id);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    throw new \Exception("Contact info request failed for user {$contact->username}! {$this->providerId} returned an error: $e");
                }
                //
                $uc = new \Hybrid_User_Contact();
                //
                $uc->identifier     = $contact->id;
                $uc->profileURL     = "https://instagram.com/{$contact->username}";
                $uc->webSiteURL     = @$contactInfo->data->website;
                $uc->photoURL       = @$contact->profile_picture;
                $uc->displayName    = @$contact->full_name;
                $uc->description    = @$contactInfo->data->bio;
                //$uc->email          = ;
                //
                $contacts[] = $uc;
            }
        }
        return $contacts;
    }
}
```

> Changing the scope "basic" to "user_profile,user_media", it shows
> different error

[image]

### UPDATE

**This is my Redirect URI**

`https://127.0.0.1/magento_241/sociallogin/social/callback/?hauth.done=Instagram`

> I'm not sure this could be the reason it's not working but green tick
> is not showing next to the Instagram Basic display as it is showing for Facebook Login.

[image: Screenshot1]

> **But my app is live here it shows live,**

[image: Screenshot2]

> Somehow if I managed to log in (after entering credentials) no matter
> what option do I choose in the below screenshot, it displays the error `Oops, an error occurred.` on this URL `https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fmagento_241%2Fsociallogin%2Fsocial%2Fcallback%2F%3Fhauth.done&response_type=code&scope=basic`

[image: Screenshot2]

**Let me know if anyone has a solution.**

Answer (score 5):

The [API has changed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/). The Url for authorization now looks different:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=XXXXXX&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code
```

Just exchange it in your request and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Scope "basic" is deprecated from what I've seen. I've solved this error in Laravel by setting scopes independently from package:

```
return Socialite::driver('instagram')
    ->setScopes(['user_profile'])
    ->redirect();
```

Maybe if you remove `public $scope = "basic";` it could solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

While your `redirect_uri` might be working properly, have you made sure to add that URI to your Instagram App settings list of **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs**? If not, you will encounter an `invalid redirect uri` message.

To add this URI, go to your Facebook App's dashboard, then click on the sidebar to Basic Display:

[image: Facebook App Dashboard sidebar]

Then, scrolling down on the right side, you will see the space for adding Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.